# Why does dateutil.parser('May 10, 2019') return inconsistent year values when there is/isn't a space after the comma?

Tags: python-3.6, python-dateutil

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('May 10,2019')
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 10, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('May 10, 2019')
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 10, 0, 0)
```

Notice the space or no space after the comma.

It seems to be parsing a two digit year when there is no space after the comma, and a four digit year when there is a space after the comma.

Is this expected?

The versions I have:

$ pip show python-dateutil
Name: python-dateutil
Version: 2.8.0

$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be much help, but should at least provide some extra information.

It's not parsing a two-digit year in one case and a four-digit one in the other, it's actually defaulting to *the current year* in the case without a space, where it can't parse the year for some reason.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("August 06, 1881")
datetime.datetime(1881, 8, 6, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("August 06,1881")
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 6, 0, 0)
```

This issue has since been opened on Github
https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/939 and seems to be related to the fact that the comma can be used as a separator *within* times (say something like 23,5 seconds). It also apparently used to work: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/1075
So there's hope for a fix, but it will involve diving into the code.

A band-aid fix of applying `.replace(",", ", ")` to the string might work in the meantime, but it's certainly not the easiest thing to read.

This could potentially be useful too, but the Github issue is probably the best:
https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo.JUMP